# Not able to select and click on a button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find element by different methods, by css, classname, tagname, etc but it just won't click on the button.

```
<button class="button  add-to-cart__button sidebar__add-to-cart-button" data-automated-test="submit" type="submit">
                                                                  Add to Cart       
                                                                          
                                                                      </button>
```

Here are some variations I have tried, but not a complete list. I also tried locating by cssSelector and tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("button.add-to-cart__button.sidebar__add-to-cart-button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.className("button.add-to-cart__button.sidebar__add-to-cart-button")).submit();

driver.findElement(By.className("button.add-to-cart_button.sidebar_add-to-cart-button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = ' button.add-to-cart__button.sidebar__add-to-cart-button']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = ' button.add-to-cart__button.sidebar__add-to-cart-button']")).submit();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'sidebar__add-to-cart-button']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'sidebar__add-to-cart-button']")).submit();

driver.findElement(By.className("form.add-to-cart__form sidebar__add-to-cart-form")).submit();
```

Any suggestions on how I should try and locate this button? I am wondering if there is something interfering with selenium being able to locate or click the button.

Thank you!

Comment: Check if it is in `iframe`.

Comment: The site does not have any iframes, but thank you for the suggestion to check that.

Comment: What error you are getting. And please share what code you have written till now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting an unable to locate element error. I just updated the description to include some things I have tried so far.

Comment: I think the issue is that there are are multiple buttons using the same class. Tried using the xpath index option but maybe I'm using it incorrectly. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"submit\"]//submit[3]")).submit();

Comment: I resolved the issue. I was being a complete noob, I just started working with selenium and didn't realize I could get the relative xpath from right clicking in developer tools and selecting Copy Xpath. After getting the xpath that way the automation was able to click on the button.